# How to clean up the contact information in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am not that experienced with Google Sheets, just wanted to preface that. I am looking to have this sheet cleaned up so that each Address record also contains the Owner, Company, and all contact information associated with the property in a single record (row, etc.).

Address, City, ST, Zip, APN, Owner, Companies, People + All contact info for each person (phones + emails).

The current output is the only way the existing platform exports the info to maintain accurate data associated with each record.

I have included the link, you can see the people, phone, and email are all in single columns.

Any insight would be highly appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRI21tBNizzD8BYg_M4TNZ9P-bb0IVb4PtTqzcW8SuQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Your spreadsheet requires permission to gain access. This will limit the number of people who may be able to help you. Please provide a copy of your spreadsheet that is accessible to anyone with the url. On a tangent, please don't expect users to read your spreadsheet in order to understand your question. You must supply all this information in the body of your question.

Comment: Please also include what research you have already done to solve this problem, what formulas or scripts you have tried and what the results were, and (somewhere in the sheet) what the exact expected results are alongside the results your own formulas or scripts produced incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

### SPLIT Function

You can SPLIT the text around a specified character or string, and return each fragment in a separate cell. 
**Google Support:**  [SPLIT Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

### Syntax

```
=SPLIT(text, delimiter,
       [split_by_each], 
       [remove_empty_text])
```

### Sample Formula

```
=SPLIT(A2,",")
```

Comment: The OP did not  want to SPLIT a single string but rather was describing combining multiple strings in a single cell.   JOIN or TEXTJOIN would be more appropriate.